# What apps are prevented from Amazon Fire tablet?

Tags: applications, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I am thinking of getting an Amazon Fire tablet HD 8. However, I have heard that Amazon restricts the apps that can be installed on it. Is this the case? Or is it just the Google Play store is not available? Because, I've also read that because it's Android-based, it is possible to install Google Play Store.

Can APKs be downloaded/installed from other sources? Specifically, I need to know if particular apps are available on it (FlipAClip, Soundtrap) as not having these would be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

It's Android, so most apps should work by sideloading. The only way to know if the app is incompatible is by physically testing the apps on the device. If they turn out not to work, you can simply flash a custom ROM and problem solved.

Comment: "simply flash a custom rom" - HaHa ROTFL, this man has humour! :)